Can't configure Windows to reply me with proper IP address from ping utility
I have a problem with my OS. The ping utility is returning me wrong IP address when I try to ping local hostname server.
On my server I have 3 interfaces:
Ethernet0,
Ethernet1,
Ethernet2
The primary interface with preferred static IP is Ethernet0. It also has lowest metric in the OS route table and also as the only one it has a gateway assigned. With Ethernet0 I am connected to a domain network 'example.local'. I have DNS servers set statically on this network interface.
Rest of the interfaces (Ethernet1 and Ethernet2) doesn't have gateway but they have static IP assigned.
Now to the problem. When I run nslookup I get this response:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> nslookup server01.example.local
Server:  dc01.example.local
Address:  100.72.10.133
Name:    server01.example.local
Address:  100.72.10.137

but when I run ping I get this response:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> ping server01.example.local

Pinging server01.example.local [100.76.26.142] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 100.76.26.142: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 100.76.26.142: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 100.76.26.142: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 100.76.26.142: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 100.76.26.142:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

The IP '100.72.10.137' from nslookup is my preferred static IP from primary NIC.
The IP '100.76.26.142' from ping is my static ip from Ethernet2 NIC.
What I am trying to achieve is that when I put 'server01.example.local' in my program's settings located directly on this server01, then the program will contact localhost with LAN IP of primary NIC (100.72.10.137). I know this can be resolved by adding '127.0.0.1 server01.example.local' to the hosts file but I want to more deeply understand this problem.
Why do I have different response in ping utility? I already disabled 'Disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP' in the NIC. I also disabled the service 'TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper'. I am 100% sure that my hosts file is empty. I restarted server, removed cache (ipconfig /flushdns). I assume that ping should now try to resolve the address using the DNS servers on primary NIC only. However it seems like there is another underlying component or logic in Windows OS which returns me wrong IP address using ping.

.local is a /bad/ tld replacement to use, specificly, mDNS uses it. Recently, ICANN has proposed using .internal as official TLD for internal networks. If you have or will be using a proper domain in the future, consider using subdomains like lan.mydomain.com
While not 100% positive this is causing your problem, i would be looking for active mDNS services in your network potentially causing this. Double so if you have Mac devices in your network.

Also, whats your source IP (the one you are pinging from) ?

How come ping got an answer from Ethernet2? I thought Ethernet2 is not supposed to have a gateway to the network.

Note also that recent Windows versions give less importance to the interface metrics than did previous versions.

this will be dictated by your route table. if you want us to walk you through it, please add your route table and the IP address you are pinging from to your question.

@Silbee the .local root domain I presented here is only as an example. In reality I am not using .local root domain.
What do you mean by source IP? Source IP should be the IP from Ethernet0 because this NIC has lowest metric or am I wrong?

@FrankThomas I am not sure if I would like to put whole route table here. Anyway I checked it again and the Ethernet0 interface has the lowest metric BUT the Ethernet2 interface has the same metric as Ethernet0. Both interfaces has 271 metric. The third interface has 331 metric.

Also I forget to mention that OS is Windows Server 2016. Sorry for that missing piece of information.

@Mi1anovic Wont hurt to check, right ? Ping also has a "-S sourceaddr" option to chose which network to use.

@Silbee thx! I tried that and the result is: 1. Ping from source Ethernet0 to 'server01.example.local' ends with Request timed out. 2. Ping from source Ethernet2 to 'server01.example.local' is working...

Could be, check your firewall for ICMP traffic rules (for all 3 public, private, domain) and see if either LAN is "misconfigured" to use the wrong settings.

@Silbee Windows Firewall is off. I don't have additional firewall software on the server. The network LAN firewall shouldn't be intercepting this traffic because when I ping another server on the LAN network I receive valid IP response.

Here is the printscreen from the ping with source: https://imgur.com/RpWNGFn

Okay I found out that in a route table of my OS, two interfaces had same metric value. I changed metric values of interfaces from Automatic to Manual and I set lowest metric value on the Ethernet0 interface. I also needed to change metric value on Ethernet1 and Ethernet2 interfaces to higher value. Now the ping is returning me the correct IP address.
I still don't understand how ping (underlaying OS DNS resolution flow) decide which IP address will be returned when two NICs have the same metric value in this case.

ok, for any given source IP, one interface/IP is going to respond to all ping requests regardless of which IP on the target system you are pinging. Which IP you ping is not part of the equation at all. the only thing that matters is the source IP in the echo packets, and the system will use whatever is the most appropriate route to reach that destination (most specific route, and then based on metrics if there is more than one path of equal specificity).

Thanks I get that. However do you think it is possible to fully understand the decision why OS is always returning one specific IP when two NICs have the same metric in route table? That thing about the path in route table - the path is very simple in this case because the ping is done against the localhost (computer) name. The path I believe is the same in both cases. So I still don't know the answer - which logic is applied in OS when deciding what IP will be returned from ping utility in this case?

Paths (exit interfaces) have metrics, but destinations have specificity. routes will be sorted by the most specific route to the destination, and metric is only ever considered if there are two destinations with equal specificity that use different exit interfaces. This would be a lot easier if you showed us your route table. Also, .local and localhost are not at all related. using .local actually makes things more complicated because it uses mDNS.

I reverted my changes back. Here is the route table with nslookup and ping: https://imgur.com/a/5e9yP8Q

what IP are you pinging from?

Well that's not important. From technical perspective I understand it is important but not in the real problematic I have. My problem is when I add 'server01.example.local' to an app config to my app which is hosted in this server and I run it from this server I have a connection error. After I change metric on nics this problem is solved as same as ping IP output. However when I try to ping using different source IPs I end with same destination IP. You can see it in the comment section under my main question as imgur link.

You werent having DNS resolution problems. The first thing windows does is check if the name you have given is the computers name. In this case, it is (server01.example.local). Your server has 3 IP addresses, the server's name is bound to all 3! So where you initiated your ping from was probably the deciding measure on where to reply from. It looks to me like what you want is to bind your webapp to eth0.

a lot of the issue is going to be coming from using .local. it sounds like your situation requires more stability and customization than zero-conf/UPNP protocols can provide. by design ALL interfaces on a host will advertise the same .local name, due to mDNS, so it can't imply a single IP on a multi-homed server.

@Silbee yes I want to bind my app to eth0 and this works only when eth0 has lowest metric. What I don't understand why when two NIC have same metric I still get response from one NIC only and that's et2 in my case. What logic is behind this?

@FrankThomas I mentioned it under the main question's discussion: The .local is just example I put in this question to hide my real local domain name. I am just trying to be consistent with what I put in the question here. In reality my AD DS domain does not end with .local.

Binding to a network interface can be done programmaticly. If you have no control over the code, you can only hope the service/app has exposed this functionality for you to make use of. As for which adapter windows sees as 'main' interface when metrics are equal, i cannot tell you and you'd probably need to contact microsoft for.  I wouldnt be surprised if it leads to random selection.

@Silbee got it. Thanks for help. The idea of binding to a nic programmatically is interesting. Anyway I will try to contact MS.

My guess about what happened :

Windows sent out DHCP requests on all the interfaces, and they
were all answered, thus gaining a gateway address
Windows decided that Ethernet2 was the fastest and adopted it
as the main interface
The ping was then made via Ethernet2.

This guess requires that all the interfaces be connected to
the network.
Windows 10/11 give much less importance to the metrics than
previous versions.
